# Issue in printing data under different classes on html page, together using beautiful soup

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape prices for devices from a website, prices are mentioned as 2 types on the website:

1. Single Price Eg.$99.99
2. Price Range Eg. "$49.99" to "$99.99"

Single price values are mentioned under a single class and I am able to extract those values but Price range are mentioned in 2 classes Eg.

```html
<div class="gridPrice">"$199.99" 
 <span class="multiDevicePrice-to">to</span> "$399.99"
```

Prices mentioned as range are in double quotes while prices as single values are without any quotes.

I am using the following code:

```
import csv
import urllib2
import sys  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
for anchor1 in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "listGrid-price"},text=True):
    if anchor1.string:
        print unicode(anchor1.string).strip()
for anchor2 in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "gridPrice"},text=True):
    if anchor2.string:
        print unicode(anchor2.string).strip()
```

In output I am not getting values for price-ranges, What I need is list of all prices together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.stripped_strings` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) to get an iterable of all (stripped) text values in a given tag:

```
for anchor1 in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "listGrid-price"}):
    textcontent = u' '.join(anchor1.stripped_strings)
    if textcontent:
        print textcontent
```

You may have to select just one or two values of those; `itertools.islice` could help there:

```
from itertools import islice

for anchor1 in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "listGrid-price"}):
    textcontent = u' '.join(islice(anchor1.stripped_strings, 0, 3, 2))
    if textcontent:
        print textcontent
```

The `islice` call only selects the first and third elements, which are the from and to prices in the grid.